# In Kohana 3, how do you figure out errors made during a query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, kohana, kohana-3

I'm using Kohana 3.

I'm writing an update query, and it is working for everything except this one section.

If I do a `var_dump()` on the results of `$db->execute()` I get either a 1 or 0 to say it failed or not. It is failing in this example (returning 0).

How can I figure out what error is happening? It justs seems to be silenty failing at the time being. I tried doing `echo mysql_error()` but it didn't work, as I expected, as Kohana 3's db library uses PDO I'm pretty sure.

How can I figure out the error that has occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing this after calling `$db->execute()`:

```
echo Database::instance()->last_query
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Controller run the profiler:

```
$this->profiler = new Profiler;
```

And then after rendering View you'll see a list of queries that were executed. Try them out by connecting to the database or by using some software (like MySQL Query Browser).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It should throw an exception if it's a SQL error. You can catch this and echo it to get the error. See http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=crud_with_the_query_builder