# KOHANA - ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Cannot use object of type Model as array

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm

Can you advise on how to resolve the following error:

`ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Cannot use object of type Model_Branch as array`

Please see controller:

```
public function action_view($agent_id='') {
        $agent =  ORM::factory('agent', $agent_id);

        if ($agent->loaded()) {

            $values = $agent->as_array();
            $branches = $agent->branches->find_all()->as_array();

            // Show page
            $this->template->title = $agent->company_name;
            $this->template->content = View::factory('agent/view')
                    ->bind('title', $this->template->title)
                    ->bind('values', $values)
                    ->bind('branches', $branches);
        } else {
            Request::instance()->redirect('agent');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show lines where Exception throwing. Seems like its not Controller, but View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need as_array() there. Database_Result objects behave as array by default, you can do `foreach ($branches as $b) echo $b->id` there without even converting it to array;

```
Database_Result implements Countable, Iterator, SeekableIterator, ArrayAccess
```

The only current usage of Database_Result::as_array() method would be for generating key => val arrays, as I pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393051/favourite-kohana-tips-features/3381938#3381938). You currently can't convert this to array of database results, although it [seems logical at first](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/2860).

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
$branches = $agent->branches->find_all();
$branches = $branches->as_array();
```

It might work, sometimes you need to declare it before you transform it.